# Grub menu not showing after ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 18.10, grub-efi

Guys my laptop had only windows 8 version. Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.10 version in it. But the problem is it is now booting directly to windows.

As seen in forms I tried turning off secure boot and fast boot but still the problem remains.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/  Why install an EOL release? (18.10 means the 2018-October release with *yy.mm* format used; it was not a LTS or *long-term-support* release so *release-upgraded* to 19.04 before it went EOL; that upgrade path is gone as 19.04 is EOL too)

Answer (score 1):

I have used boot-repair before to successfully fix these sorts of dual-boot issues, see here:

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Other than [@codlord](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239023/1037999) answer (that in my opinion should be the first thing to do), maybe there is the chance that GRUB menu is hidden and Windows is the default: this means that you cannot select Ubuntu because you cannot see the GRUB menu.

If `boot-repair` doesn't help you, try to open as root the file `/etc/default/grub` and find the following variables:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE
```

if `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` exists, comment it with a #

Also, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` (maybe it is currently set in your machine as "hidden")

After saving the file, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.